# Where should I start looking to create a plugin that extends Rails 3 finds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, rubygems, find

Prior to Rails 3, creating a plugin to extend `find` was relatively easy: basically override the `find` method itself in `ActiveRecord::Base`, calling `super` if needed.

Now that Arel is being used in Rails 3, (specifically I'm using Rails 3.1), how would I go about doing something similar?  The problem is that many of the old `find` methods are deprecated in favor of scopes like `where`, `order`, `limit`, etc.  At what point(s) in the Rails source should I try to override the default behavior?

I'm sure it's going to be a bit more convoluted than this, but the closest thing I can find that seems like it might be appropriate is the `construct_finder_arel` method in `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After digging through Rails source, regardless of Arel being used, `find_by_sql` method is called on whatever model is performing the find.  This can be extended via `alias_method_chain` as follows:

```
find_by_sql_with_customization(*args)
  results = find_by_sql_without_customization
  # do something with results here
  results
end

alias_method_chain :find_by_sql, :customization
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted considering it's the right answer.  Would the downvoter care to explain in a comment, or are you going to hide behind your internet anonymity?